# parsing an xml schema to read/list all elements

Tags: java, groovy, xsd

So, I wish to parse an xml schema and list all the elements along with their annotation and type. I looked at some java possibilities - the closest was XSOM. It seems like driving a truck trailer to get some milk from the neighborhood store.

I looked at JAXB, but there's no parse and list all elements against schemata.

I don't want to validate- only want to list the elements/type/annotation.

Groovy's xmlsurper is a decent parser, but can't parse XSD. Anything you know in Java,Groovy (or python)?

thank you for your time.

Comment: Why won't xmlslurper parse XSD? Isn't XSD also XML?

Comment: i tried running xmlsurper against an xsd, parsing failed([Fatal Error] : The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.).

Comment: the error is probably because the xsd file has whitespace before the xml directive. you can try trim it with something like: XmlSlurper().parseText(xsdFilecontents?.trim())

Answer (score 0):

The [SAX parser](http://www.saxproject.org/) is very simple.